# mysql installation issue in debain wheezy

Tags: apt

while we configuring  IMS Kamailio , facing issues on MySQL installation.

OS : Debian 7 (Wheezy)

While we issue apt-get install mysql-server-5.6, getting below error:

apt-get install mysql-server-5.6

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

mysql-community-server : Depends: libaio1 (>= 0.3.93) but it is not
 installable

Depends: libnuma1 (>= 2.0.8~rc4) but it is not
 installable

Recommends: mysql-client (= 5.6.28-1debian7)

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Note:in mysql list

added below lines:

deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian wheezy mysql-5.6

deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian wheezy mysql-5.6

deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian wheezy mysql-apt-config

Can any one help us to resolve this problem.

Thank you so much in advance.

Regards,

Kranti

Comment: what happens when you run `apt-get -f install`  ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the packages in MySQL APT repository have dependencies not available in Debian APT repository.

However, Kamailio works with the version of MySQL server from Debian repository. You don't need to add http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian to your system APT sources list. Try by removing it from there, then do **apt-get update; apt-get install mysql-server;**.